# Reactjs - multiple conditions to show components - if/else blocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and looking to transform an old js file into a reactjs component. I've written the components out and I am trying to now append the same/similar if/else logic structure

I know you can do if logic like this

```
return (
    <div>
    { true && <AddAccount /> }
    { false && <AccountAdded /> }
    </div>
);
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

so should the code look something like this - with lots of inline style conditional operators?

```
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
      ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

//old js

```
{if isset($interview)}

    {* First Information Section *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_first_section.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}


    <div class="row show-for-small-only" style="height: 50px;"></div>

    {* Interview Tips Section *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_interview_tips.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}

    {* Conference Calls Section *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_call.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}


    {if $user_type eq 'professional'}

        {* after interview section - professional *}
        {* ******************************************** *}

        {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_after_interview_professional.tpl" }
        {include file="$base_path$path"}

    {elseif $user_type eq 'employer'}

        {* after interview section - employer *}
        {* ******************************************** *}

        {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_after_interview_employer.tpl" }
        {include file="$base_path$path"}

    {/if}

    {* Thank you page *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_feedback_thank_you.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}

{else}

    {* No Interview Page *}
    {* ******************************************** *}

    {assign  var="path" value="/views/video/video_no_interview.tpl" }
    {include file="$base_path$path"}

{/if}
```

//current react js attempt

```
return (
  <div>
    {/*  check if the user has an interview upcoming in the next 30 minutes */}
    {/* if isset($interview) */}

      {/*  First Information Section */}
      <VideoFirstSection lang={lang} />

      <div className='row show-for-small-only' style={{height: '50px'}} />

      {/*  Interview Tips Section */}
      <VideoInterviewTips lang={lang} />

      {/*  Conference Calls Section */}
      <VideoCall lang={lang} />
      {/* include file="$base_path$path" */}

      {/* if $user_type eq 'professional' */}
        {/*  after interview section - professional */}
        <VideoAfterInterviewProfessional lang={lang} />
      {/* elseif $user_type eq 'employer' */}
        {/*  after interview section - employer */}
        <VideoAfterInterviewEmployer lang={lang} />
      {/* /if */}

      {/*  Thank you page */}
      <VideoFeedbackThankYou lang={lang} />

    {/* else */}
      {/*  No Interview Page */}
      <VideoNoInterview lang={lang} />
    {/* /if */}

  </div>
)
```

//latest attempt - getting unexpected token lang

```
{isset($interview) ? 
  {/*  First Information Section */}
  <VideoFirstSection lang={lang} />

  <div className='row show-for-small-only' style={{height: '50px'}} />

  {/*  Interview Tips Section */}
  <VideoInterviewTips lang={lang} />

  {/*  Conference Calls Section */}
  <VideoCall lang={lang} />

  {($userType eq 'professional') ?
    <VideoAfterInterviewProfessional lang={lang} />
  : ($userType eq 'employer') ?
    <VideoAfterInterviewEmployer lang={lang} />
  }

  {/*  Thank you page */}
  <VideoFeedbackThankYou lang={lang} />
: (
  {/*  No Interview Page */}
  <VideoNoInterview lang={lang} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say create Separate component for if and else conditions and then you can render them , it will a lot more clear

```
return (
  <div>
    {/*  check if the user has an interview upcoming in the next 30 minutes */}
    {/* if isset($interview) */}

    {isset($interview)? <IfComponent/>: <ElseComponent/>}


  </div>
)
```

IfComponent

```
render () {
    return (<div>
      {/*  First Information Section */}
      <VideoFirstSection lang={lang} />

      <div className='row show-for-small-only' style={{height: '50px'}} />

      {/*  Interview Tips Section */}
      <VideoInterviewTips lang={lang} />

      {/*  Conference Calls Section */}
      <VideoCall lang={lang} />
      {/* include file="$base_path$path" */}

      {($user_type eq 'professional')? <VideoAfterInterviewProfessional lang={lang} />: ($user_type eq 'employer')? <VideoAfterInterviewEmployer lang={lang} />: null }


      {/*  Thank you page */}
      <VideoFeedbackThankYou lang={lang} /></div>
    ) 

}
```

ElseComponent

```
render() {
   return (
        <div>
         {/*  No Interview Page */}
         <VideoNoInterview lang={lang} />
        </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: ^ I've updated my example -- I am getting - unexpected token lang